# Loop structure, nested lists.

Tags: python, loops, indexing

This is a simple test function that is synonymous to my actual code. 
So I have an array of data structured like this,

a=[[1,2,3,4,5],[0,3,6,8,10],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]]

I am trying to loop over it so that in each pass we get, the first element of the first list, first element in the second list, and then each element in the first list of the third list.

Like this.

```
for i,j in enumerate(a):
     print 'iterations',i
     print a[0][i]
     print a[1][i]
     print a[2][i][0]
     print a[2][i][1]
     print a[2][i][2]
     print a[2][i][3]
```

But for some reason I cant get passed i=2. Can anyone explain why and how I can rectify this. 
Thanks. There's no error it just ends at i=2.

Comment: yes it ends at 2 because u have list of three list at first level

Comment: Simple: `len(a) == 3` in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closely at structure of your data:

```
a = [
        [1,2,3,4,5],
        [0,3,6,8,10],
        [ 
            [1,2,3,4],
            [1,2,3,4],
            [1,2,3,4],
            [1,2,3,4],
            [1,2,3,4]
        ]
    ]
```

You clearly have only 3 elements in `a`, so 2 is the last index...

Comment: Note that `pprint.pprint` can be used to spot this kind of error.